# Adding image to Android wear app - beginner

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm developing an Android wear app and attempting to overlay text with an image.

In main_activity.xml I have :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher1.png" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myImageView"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Android studio complains that `cannot resolve symbol @drawable/ic_launcher1.png`

So to fix I generate `refs.xml` in folder `values`

refs.xml content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <drawable name="ic_launcher1.png">test</drawable>
</resources>
```

Where do I add the image `ic_launcher1.png` ?

Comment: have you checked any of the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `refs.xml`, but you need folders  `res` and `res/drawable` and the file `ic_launcher1.png` to be inside the drawable folder

[Drawable Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

and your xml must be like that

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

use only `ic_launcher1` dont use .png extension

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher1"
```

Comment: as file name treated as Resource ID (in R.java) for all the resources like drawable , strings , layouts etc,So no need to add extension refer resources with only IDs

Answer (score 1):

Your main_activity.xml must be like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myImageView"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

You don't need the refs.xml file.